# jquery datepicker focus event

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have 2 datefields in a form using jquery datepicker.
Clicking the first field and choosing a date will autofill the second datefield with the choosen date of datefield1 + one day - Everything is working fine.

But if I click the submit-button of the form the date of the second datefield (thats autofilled) is not transmitted, this means its empty. But if I click the second datefield manually and choose a date via datepicker, the date is submitted correctly thru the form.

Is there any possibility to set the second (autofilled) datefield as clicked or something like that, so that the second date ist submitted correctly?

Here is the script:

```
$(function() {

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#dt1").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
            minDate: 0,
            onSelect: function (date) {
                var date2 = $('#dt1').datepicker('getDate');
                date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
                $('#dt2').datepicker('setDate', date2);
                //sets minDate to dt1 date + 1
                $('#dt2').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date2);
            }
        });
        $('#dt2').datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
            onClose: function () {
                var dt1 = $('#dt1').datepicker('getDate');
                console.log(dt1);
                var dt2 = $('#dt2').datepicker('getDate');
                if (dt2 <= dt1) {
                    var minDate = $('#dt2').datepicker('option', 'minDate');
                    $('#dt2').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Regards
Schani

Comment: Hey, i have created the jsfiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/9dr4p/, onclick of the submit button, i am able to get both the values (Observe the console in developer tool) Getting like: som.php?dt1=23-Apr-2014&dt2=24-Apr-2014

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for creating a fiddle for me. Really, even if the second field is not clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution by myself. Simply but  $('#dt2' ).focus(); in the first function:

```
$("#dt1").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function (date) {
            var date2 = $('#dt1').datepicker('getDate');
            date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
            $('#dt2').datepicker('setDate', date2);
            //sets minDate to dt1 date + 1
            $('#dt2').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date2);
$('#dt2' ).focus();
        }
    });
    $('#dt2').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        onClose: function () {
            var dt1 = $('#dt1').datepicker('getDate');
            console.log(dt1);
            var dt2 = $('#dt2').datepicker('getDate');
            if (dt2 <= dt1) {
                var minDate = $('#dt2').datepicker('option', 'minDate');
                $('#dt2').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:
    $('#dt2').datepicker('setDate', date2).trigger('change');
instead of:
    $('#dt2').datepicker('setDate', date2);
```

Comment: Hi Adrian, thank you for your fast reply. I tryed it, but im sorry it is not working.

Comment: No clue? Maybe it is important. Hidden form fields are used to catch the datepicker dates, but they are only filled with the data if the datepicker datefield is clicked. The data of the second (autofilled) datefield is not submitted to the form.